# animate a logo for 3 seconds in the front page and then show an image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I am trying to get an animation from the logo to the image slider without leaving the page or reloading I like to know the best way with jquery to achieve this, I'm learning web-development  any help would be great thank you**

```
<div class="intro">



<img scr="logo.png">

<h3> website title</h3>

</div>

<div class="slides">

<ul>

<li>

<img scr="img.jpg" />

</li>

</ul>

</div>
<script>
$(function(){ $('.intro').hide.show(3000);});
</script>
```

Comment: Please make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/VGwC4/)**</kbd>.

```
$(function() {
  $('.intro').delay(5000).fadeOut(600, function() {
    $('.slides').fadeIn(600);
  });
});
```

Comment: what could cause the animation not to work on safari? it works on chrome which is run under the same engine as safari. and firefox is slower. thank you

Comment: Different browser, different rendering...and about Safari I really don't know why doesn't working.

Comment: thank you, @mdesdev; it was my bad I just updated safari and now it works. sorry and thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.intro').hide().delay(3000).show();`
Haven't tested this, but make sure you have parens after your function calls (e.g. `.hide()` not `.hide`.

Also using `delay(3000)` to delay the showing for 3s instead of fading in for 3s.

One more tip: try using CSS to hide the `.intro` block:

```
.intro {
    display: none;
}
```

To show the slider, just do the same with `.slide`:

```
$('.slide').show();
```

Comment: thank you that part is working, the delay function is very useful just added in thank you. the other part is to show the jquery slider right after the logo animation is done.